# Como mostrar os dados de 2 tabelas em um grid?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando Windows Forms e queria poder mostrar os dados de 2 tabelas em umgGrid, pelo comando SQL eu consigo fazer isso

```sql
SELECT SU.SUBCATEGORIAID, SU.NOME, SU.CATEGORIAID, C.NOME 
FROM SUBCATEGORIA SU 
INNER JOIN CATEGORIA C 
ON SU.CATEGORIAID = C.CATEGORIAID
```

Eu queria poder fazer mais o menos esse código, para poder mostrar no grid os dados de 2 tabelas, eu só conseguir fazer isso

```
public List<SubCategoria> Localizar(string valor)
{
    if (valor != string.Empty)
    {
        return _contexto.SubCategorias
        .Where(c => c.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(valor.ToUpper()))
        .ToList();

    }
    else
    {
        return _contexto.SubCategorias.ToList();
    }
}
```

Aqui ele só ta mostrado 3 campos `SubCategoriaId`, `Nome`, `CategoriaId`
Eu quero poder mostra esses 3 campos mais o nome da categoria.

Comment: Você só quer poder trazer um campo a mais no resultado? `Subcategoria` tem propriedade de navegação com `Categoria`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linq e aproveite o `join` .
Crie também uma classe para seu retorno de dados, onde receba o retorno da query. Tem um pessoal do MVC que gosta de chamar esse tipo de classe de ModelView.

Exemplo :

**1 -**

Crio uma classe para ter o resultado tipado

```
public class ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid
{
    public int SubCategoriaId {get;set;}
    public string SubCategoriaNome {get;set;}
    public int CategoriaId {get;set;}
    public string CategoriaNome {get;set;}
}
```

**2 -** 
Alterei seu método localizar para o seguinte :

```
public List<ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid> Localizar(string valor)
{
    if (valor != string.Empty)
    {
        /*
        SELECT SU.SUBCATEGORIAID, SU.NOME, SU.CATEGORIAID, C.NOME 
        FROM SUBCATEGORIA SU 
        INNER JOIN CATEGORIA C 
        ON SU.CATEGORIAID = C.CATEGORIAID
        */

        //Traduzindo em Linq seria algo assim, onde _contexto é seu DbContext.                  
        var minhaQuery = from su in _contexto.SubCategoria
            join c in _contexto.Categoria on su.CATEGORIAID equals c.CATEGORIAID   //Assim que fazemos o inner join no Linq atenção para usar "equals" ao invés do operador "=".
            where c.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(valor.ToUpper())
            select new ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid { SubCategoriaId = su.SUBCATEGORIAID, SubCategoriaNome = su.Nome,CategoriaId = su.CATEGORIAID, CategoriaNome = c.NOME };//Perceba que o select é um tipo anonimo onde coloco os nomes dos retornos como se fossem "alias" do SQL. Assim os nomes e tipos sendo compatíveis com a classe ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid


        return minhaQuery.ToList(); //Aqui quando transformo em lista informo que tipo de objetos tenho na lista.

    }
    else
    {
        //Aqui simplesmente repeti por questões de simplicidade e removi o where.
        var minhaQuery = from su in _contexto.SubCategoria
            join c in _contexto.Categoria on su.CATEGORIAID equals c.CATEGORIAID                
            select new ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid { SubCategoriaId = su.SUBCATEGORIAID, SubCategoriaNome = su.Nome,CategoriaId = su.CATEGORIAID, CategoriaNome = c.NOME };

        return minhaQuery.ToList();
    }
}
```

}

**3 -**
Informe o datasource de seu DataGrid.

```
MinhaDataGrid.Datasource = Localizar("CategoriaTeste");
```

**4 -**

```
Seja feliz! :)
```

Veja esse exemplo que criei em https://dotnetfiddle.net/yftz5C

Tentei fazer algo simples. Espere que te ajude.

Comment: Olha o erro que ta dando 
return minhaQuery.ToList<ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid>();

Comment: Olá @AlyssonBormann , fiz uma correção no meu código.  No select agora ao invés de ser do tipo anônimo, agora já informo o tipo `select new ResultadoParaMinhaDataGrid` depois basta informar `minhaQuery.ToList()` que já compila.

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi bem, você já tem o método `Localizar` que te retorna uma **lista de objetos** do tipo `Subcategoria`.

O que você precisa fazer é relacionar essa lista com um `DataGridView`.

Vou assumir que você tem dentro da objeto `Subcategoria` uma propriedade `Categoria`, ok?

Primeiro, vamos criar uma propriedade de `Subcategoria` que retorne o nome da `Categoria`.

```
public string NomeCategoria {
   return this.Categoria.Nome;
}
```

Já no local onde você chamou o método `Localizar`, faz o relacionamento do resultado com o `DataGridView`. Assim:

```
List<Subcategoria> result = Localizar();
MeuDataGrid.DataSource = result;
```

Através da opção ***EditColumns***, que você encontra na lista de propriedades, é possível gerenciar as colunas que serão exibidas no seu grid.

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa fazer uma sub consulta com as categorias.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class BuscarCategoriaSubCategorias : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String valor = TextBox1.Text;

            using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
            {
                var qrInSubCategoria = ctx.SubCategoria.AsQueryable();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
                {
                    qrInSubCategoria = qrInSubCategoria
                        .Where(C => C.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(valor.ToUpper()));
                }

                var qrInCategoria = qrInSubCategoria
                    .Select(SC => new
                    {
                        SubCategoria = SC,
                        Categoria = ctx.Categoria.FirstOrDefault(C => C.CategoriaId == SC.CategoriaId)
                    })
                    .Select(SC => new ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid
                    {
                        SubCategoriaId = SC.SubCategoria.SubCategoriaId,
                        SubCategoriaNome = SC.SubCategoria.Nome,
                        CategoriaId = SC.Categoria.CategoriaId,
                        CategoriaNome = SC.Categoria.Nome,
                    }).ToList();

                GridView1.DataSource = qrInCategoria;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable, NotMapped]
    public class ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid
    {
        public int SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoriaNome { get; set; }
        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public string CategoriaNome { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Aspx;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BuscarCategoriaSubCategorias.aspx.cs" Inherits="stackoverflow.BuscarCategoriaSubCategorias" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Sub Categoria"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Buscar" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Modelo Entity;

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace stackoverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class stackoverflowEntities : DbContext
    {
        public stackoverflowEntities()
            : base("name=stackoverflowEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SubCategoria> SubCategoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Banco;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categoria](
    [CategoriaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DtInclusao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categoria] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoriaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert into Categoria values
('Calçados', getdate()),
('Roupas', getdate())



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubCategoria](
    [SubCategoriaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CategoriaId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubCategoria] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubCategoriaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into SubCategoria values
('havaianas',1),
('botas dakota',1),
('botas ramarim',1),
('botas jacomo',1),
('Blusa Inverno',2),
('Blusa Regata',2),
('Vestido',2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

@Guilherme J Santos entendi muito bem o método que você passou, mas ta dando erro no

`return minhaQuery.ToList<ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid>();`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz uma correção em minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo @GuilhermeJSantos, até que fim deu certo.