# Erro ao fazer um return no windows form c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda, por favor, gostaria de saber o que to fazendo de errado para esta dando esse erro na hora de retorna.
Eu quero mostra no `Grid` esses campos:

```
SubCategoriaId, SubCategoriaNome, CategoriaId, CategoriaNome
```

Eu tenho um parâmetro `string valor` para fazer uma pesquisa e me retorna esses campos, caso o valor for em branco, ele me traz todo mundo do banco.

Eu criei uma Model, para ter os resultados "tipado":

```
public class ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid
{
   public int SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
   public string SubCategoriaNome { get; set; }
   public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
   public string CategoriaNome { get; set; }        

}
```

E tenho também as model de cada uma
Categoria:

```
public class Categoria    
{        
   public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

E SubCategoria

```
public class SubCategoria
{        
    public int SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }        
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mostrar os dados de 2 tabelas em um grid?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136162/como-mostrar-os-dados-de-2-tabelas-em-um-grid)

Answer (score 2):

O que acontece é que sua instrução `LINQ` retorna um **tipo anônimo**.

```
var minhaQuery = from su in _contexto.SubCategorias
                 join c in _contexto.Catgorias on su.CategoriaId equals c.CategoriaId
                 select new { SubCategoriaId = su.SubCategoriaId, SubCategoriaNome = su.Nome, CategoriaId = su.CategoriaId, CategoriaNome = c.Nome};
```

Ao invés disso, retorne o tipo desejado pelo seu método, ou seja, `ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid`.

Ficaria assim:

```
var minhaQuery = from su in _contexto.SubCategorias
                 join c in _contexto.Catgorias on su.CategoriaId equals c.CategoriaId
                 select new ResultadoCategSubCategoriaGrid() { SubCategoriaId = su.SubCategoriaId, SubCategoriaNome = su.Nome, CategoriaId = su.CategoriaId, CategoriaNome = c.Nome};
```

Veja se funciona, no momento não tenho como testar o código.

Comment: +1 Foi justamente essa correção que fiz em minha resposta.